# Is there some way I can enable/disable the showing of a column in a table in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<select
    data-ng-model="option.selectedValue"
    data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.selects">
</select>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Street</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="grid">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
            <td>{{ row.iD }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.street }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way for me to change it so the street column becomes visible only if the `option.selectedValue` is equal to 0

Comment: You can do: <td ng-show="option.selectedValue == 0">{{row.street}}</td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on your `{{row.street}}` and `street` lines

```
<th ng-show='option.selectedValue == 0'>Street</th>
...
<td ng-show='option.selectedValue == 0'>{{row.street}}</td>
```

or

```
<th ng-hide="option.selectedValue != 0">Street</th>
...
<td ng-hide='option.selectedValue != 0'>{{row.street}}</td>
```

it's the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show. You need to hide both `header column` and the `content column`.

```
<th ng-show="option.selectedValue == 0">Street</th>
<td ng-show="option.selectedValue == 0">{{ row.street }}</td>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6FM/1/)**</kbd>